# 'Bad double value' error in Big-Query for non-null value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table with LTV column. The type of the column is STRING.
I have tried to cast this column to FLOAT64 using `CAST(LTV AS FLOAT64)`, but got "Bad double value: LTV" error (bigquery standard). I looked on the specific row that causes the error (for many rows it is worked just fine) and I saw that the value is '51.0' which looks legit. I run this query:

`SELECT
  LTV,
  LENGTH(LTV) AS len_ltv,
  SAFE_CAST(LTV AS FLOAT64) AS ltv_safe_cast,
  CASE
    WHEN LTV = '51.0' THEN 'eq'
    ELSE 'neq'
  END AS eq_str,
  CAST(SAFE_CAST(LTV AS FLOAT64) AS STRING) AS ltv_double_cast,
  CAST(SAFE_CAST(LTV AS FLOAT64) AS STRING) = LTV AS ltv_double_cast_eq_str
FROM
  mytable`

and got those [results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1942Xue89ynObUtr3FBhWYbI2KvdzaRm3/view?usp=sharing).

When I save the *problematic* row as CSV file and then upload it as a table again with "auto detect scheme" option the LTV column parsed as FLOAT64. but when I create the scheme and specify LTV column type is STRING the upload is failed ([file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P2mlU3qqJiA0tcvOm9hGfIdMKqxEKk2E/view?usp=sharing) - I hope the file remains in the same foramt).

Running `file results.csv` return "ASCII text"

Printing the file in Python:

`with open('results.csv') as f:
        print(f)`

"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='results.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"

What could be the reasons for that?

Comment: I still don't understand your question after reading it a few times. It sounds like you literally have a value of `'LTV'` in the table based on the error.

Comment: **'LTV' is just the name of the column**.  The values are floating points which converted to string, such as '12.0', '51.0', etc.. The row which causes to the problem has the value '51.0'. Please look on the result of this query ([results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1942Xue89ynObUtr3FBhWYbI2KvdzaRm3/view?usp=sharing)) to better understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the reasons for that?

What possibly happened is that you have header row (from most likely original CSV file) loaded into the BigQuery table, so that your code fails processing that exact row

You can run below example to reproduce that exact issue

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (SELECT 'LTV' AS LTV)
SELECT CAST(LTVAS FLOAT64)
FROM t
```

with result

> *Error: Bad double value: LTV*

Comment: **'LTV' is just the name of the column**. The values are floating points which converted to string, such as '12.0', '51.0', etc.. The row which causes to the problem has the value '51.0'. Please look on the result of this query ([results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1942Xue89ynObUtr3FBhWYbI2KvdzaRm3/view?usp=sharing)) to better understand the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the problem as well; it's probably a header row, not 51.0.

Comment: You wrong. It's not a header row. Please look on the result link I sent. The output of `SAFE_CAST` on this row indeed gives the value 51.0! I'm pretty sure `SAFE_CAST('LTV') !=51.0`

Comment: we are not insisting here rather trying to help you :o) the only conclusion (based on info from your question) I was able to come with - is what is in my answer. The most important evidence here is  "Bad double value: LTV" - it is just explicit statement about fact that the value is "LTV" and not "51.0" . Someone else might come with other ideas though :o)

Comment: Yes of course, I appreciate it. I can’t provide you a screen shot of the results, but I provided a link for the screen shot. In the link you may see that the result of ‘SAFE_CAST(LTV)’ is 51.0 **where LTV is a column name and not a string**.